# Subcaption package make all captions centered

Tags: horizontal-alignment, subcaption

If i include `subcaption` package, all captions of figures are centered. But i want to make captions justified text. What should i do?

P.S
I insert image by `\begin{figure}` and `\includegraphics` and make caption by `\caption`.

Comment: What should you do? How about a minimal document that replicates your current behaviour. Can you do that? It should start with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`.

Comment: In the basic LaTeX document classes `article`, `\report`, and `book`, as well as in many document classes that are based on these basic classes, `figure` and `table` captions are centered by default *unless* the caption spans more than one line. Please tell us which document class you employ.

Answer (score 1):

[`subcaption`](//ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) uses [`caption`](//ctan.org/pkg/caption) where the `singlelinecheck` setting defaults to `true` (is turned on). This setting centres the caption if it fits on a single line.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{showframe}% Just for this example
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \caption{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\ldots}
\end{figure}

\captionsetup{
  singlelinecheck = false
}

\begin{figure}
  \caption{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\ldots}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```